# NullReferenceException в IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis

С чем может быть связана это ошибка?
Нормально не гуглится, не понимаю, что с этим делать. Приложение работает, но исключение ведь почему-то появляется. В какую сторону копать вообще?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Появляется обычно после 
`"iisexpress.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Загружено "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly".`

Выходит не всегда, а раз в 10 запусков или больше. Сейчас пытаюсь еще раз воспроизвести, чтобы скопировать логи, но, как назло, не появляется

UPD

При отладке:

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: H:\GitHub\LibraryClient
"iisexpress.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Загружено "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll". 
"iisexpress.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Загружено "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.2\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll". 
"iisexpress.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Загружено "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll". 
"iisexpress.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Загружено "Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly". 
Вызвано исключение: "System.NullReferenceException" в Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Стек вызовов:

```
    >   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll!Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer.OnDisconnect(System.IntPtr pvManagedHttpContext)
```

```
    System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Сообщение = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Источник = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS
  Трассировка стека:
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer.OnDisconnect(IntPtr pvManagedHttpContext)
```

Comment: что наблюдается в логах?

Comment: @tym32167 в вопросе добавил строчку, после которой происходило исключение, но сейчас пробую дождаться его снова, но пока не появляется, хотя ничего не делал. Почему-то появляется не постоянно

Comment: трассировку стека ищите

Comment: @tym32167 обновил. оно?

Comment: @tym32167 используйте [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview) для точной диагностики с помощью ETW. Ищите проблему в вашем коде, маловероятно что это проблема IIS.

Comment: @KarenTazayan я ничего не спрашивал, но спасибо за совет :)

Comment: Я извиняюсь, опечатался :)